# Using results from method in if statement in Java

Tags: java, methods

First off I just want to say that I am relatively new to Java.  I'm running into some issues and wanted to see if someone could help me out.  Here is my code:

```
if (rs1.getString("Active_Status")!=("Y")) {

CompleteRecord record = getCompleteRecord();

String insertQuery = String.format("Insert into YMAGRMLNUP %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", 
                    record.getPROCURE_GROUP(), record.getAGREEMENT_REF(), 
                    record.getVENDOR(), record.getPURCH_FR_LOC(), 
                    record.getLINE_NBR(), record.getITEM(),
                    record.getVEN_ITEM(), record.getFC_CODE(), 
                    record.getR_STATUS(), record.getPROCESS_TS()); 
                    executeQuery(insertQuery); 
}
public CompleteRecord getCompleteRecord(String PROCURE_GROUP, String FC_CODE)
   Connection conn = null;
   PreparedStatement psV = null;
   ResultSet rsV = null;
   DSConnection dsc = new DSConnection(); 

try {
       String getValues = "SELECT POVAGRMTHD.PROCURE_GROUP, 
       POVAGRMTHD.VEN_AGRMT_REF, POVAGRMTHD.VENDOR, POVAGRMTHD.PURCH_FR_LOC, 
       POVAGRMTLN.LINE_NBR, POVAGRMTLN.ITEM, POVAGRMTLN.VEN_ITEM, 
       POVAGRMTHD.R_STATUS " +
       " FROM " +  dbProperties.getProperty("Schema") + 
       ".POVAGRMTHD, " + dbProperties.getProperty("Schema") + ".POVAGRMTLN " +
       " WHERE POVAGRMTHD.VEN_AGRMT_REF = POVAGRMTLN.VEN_AGRMT_REF 
       and POVAGRMTHD.PROCURE_GROUP = POVAGRMTLN.PROCURE_GROUP";
           Date today = new Date();
           Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(today.getTime());

           System.out.println(getValues);
           logger.debug("sql=" + getValues);
           conn = dsc.getConnection();

           psV = conn.prepareStatement(getValues);
           rsV = psV.executeQuery();

    while(rsV.next()){

        PovagrmthdDbo aPovagrmthdDbo = new PovagrmthdDbo();
        PovagrmtlnDbo aPovagrmtlnDbo = new PovagrmtlnDbo();
        aPovagrmthdDbo.setProcure_Group(rsV.getString("PROCURE_GROUP"));
        aPovagrmthdDbo.setVen_Agrmt_Ref(rsV.getString("VEN_AGRMT_REF"));
        aPovagrmthdDbo.setVendor(rsV.getString("VENDOR"));
        aPovagrmthdDbo.setPurch_Fr_Loc(rsV.getString("PURCH_FR_LOC"));
        aPovagrmtlnDbo.setLine_Nbr(rsV.getInt("LINE_NBR"));
        aPovagrmtlnDbo.setItem(rsV.getString("ITEM"));
        aPovagrmtlnDbo.setVen_Item(rsV.getString("VEN_ITEM"));
        aPovagrmthdDbo.setR_Status(rsV.getInt("R_STATUS"));

        CompleteRecord record = new 
        CompleteRecord(rsV.getString("PROCURE_GROUP"), 
        rsV.getString("AGREEMENT_REF"),
        rsV.getString("VENDOR"), rsV.getString("PURCH_FR_LOC"), 
        rsV.getInt("LINE_NBR"), rsV.getString("ITEM"),
        rsV.getString("VEN_ITEM"), FC_CODE, rsV.getInt("R_STATUS"), 
        ts.toString());
    }
```

What I'm try to do is build a record from the SQL query in my `CompleteRecord` method, then use it in my main method with an `if` statement. If the `Active_Status` is not Y I will insert this line into the YMAGRMLNUP table.  My issue is I'm not sure how to take the results from `CompleteRecord` and use them under my `if` statement.  I also need to set the `FC_CODE` to "H" if the `Active_Status` isn't Y in this same `if` statement.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare `String`s. It will not work for any Strings that are not created from literals. Use `equals`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first problem is you need to return the CompleteRecord object. You should've definitely received a compilation error here? Hrrmm. Also this is assuming that you will only ever have one result from the query?

```
CompleteRecord record = null;//move declaration outside of loop
while(rsV.next()){

    PovagrmthdDbo aPovagrmthdDbo = new PovagrmthdDbo();
    PovagrmtlnDbo aPovagrmtlnDbo = new PovagrmtlnDbo();
    aPovagrmthdDbo.setProcure_Group(rsV.getString("PROCURE_GROUP"));
    aPovagrmthdDbo.setVen_Agrmt_Ref(rsV.getString("VEN_AGRMT_REF"));
    aPovagrmthdDbo.setVendor(rsV.getString("VENDOR"));
    aPovagrmthdDbo.setPurch_Fr_Loc(rsV.getString("PURCH_FR_LOC"));
    aPovagrmtlnDbo.setLine_Nbr(rsV.getInt("LINE_NBR"));
    aPovagrmtlnDbo.setItem(rsV.getString("ITEM"));
    aPovagrmtlnDbo.setVen_Item(rsV.getString("VEN_ITEM"));
    aPovagrmthdDbo.setR_Status(rsV.getInt("R_STATUS"));

    record = new 
    CompleteRecord(rsV.getString("PROCURE_GROUP"), 
    rsV.getString("AGREEMENT_REF"),
    rsV.getString("VENDOR"), rsV.getString("PURCH_FR_LOC"), 
    rsV.getInt("LINE_NBR"), rsV.getString("ITEM"),
    rsV.getString("VEN_ITEM"), FC_CODE, rsV.getInt("R_STATUS"), 
    ts.toString());
}
return record;
```

Also change this top line

```
if (rs1.getString("Active_Status")!=("Y")) {
```

to this

```
if (!rs1.getString("Active_Status").equals("Y")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly not working code, or at least not all of it, so I'm making some assumptions.  I am assuming that the class CompleteRecord is one you created that has a set of properties meant to contain the fields of a result row from your query, and that CompleteRecord has a constructor that takes the values for those properties as parameters.  And I am assuming that you are asking the basic question of how to access those properties.

There are two ways:

(1) You can create a method of CompleteRecord for each of the properties, which retrieves that property: e.g.

```
void String getVendor() {
    return vendor;
}
```

Then your code that has the CompleteRecord instance would retrieve the property with the call:

```
String theVendor = record.getVendor();
```

(2) You can allow direct access to the property.  Do this by not declaring the property in CompleteRecord as private, and declare it as public if you want access outside the package.  Then you can access the property directly:

```
String theVendor = record.vendor;
```